# Load data from MySQL to BigQuery using Dataflow

Tags: python, mysql, google-bigquery, etl, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to load data from MySQL to BigQuery using Cloud Dataflow. Anyone can share article or work experience about load data from MySQL to BigQuery using Cloud Dataflow with Python language?

Thank you

Comment: Have you many transformations to apply or you only want to copy data ?

Comment: I only want to copy data from Mysql to BigQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [apache_beam.io.jdbc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html) to read from your MySQL database, and the [BigQuery I/O](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) to write on BigQuery.

Beam knowledge is expected, so I recommend looking at [Apache Beam Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) first.

If you are looking for something pre-built, we have the [JDBC to BigQuery Google-provided template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#java-database-connectivity-jdbc-to-bigquery), which is open-source ([here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/googlecloud-to-googlecloud/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java)), but it is written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to copy data from `MySQL` to `BigQuery`, you can firstly export your `MySql` data to `Cloud Storage`, then load this file to a `BigQuery` table.

I think no need using `Dataflow` in this case because you don't have complex transformations and business logics. It only corresponds to a copy.

[Export](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/import-export-csv#customize-csv-format) the `MySQL` data to `Cloud Storage` via a `sql` query and `gcloud` cli :

```bash
gcloud sql export csv INSTANCE_NAME gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME \
--database=DATABASE_NAME \
--offload \
--query=SELECT_QUERY \
--quote="22" \
--escape="5C" \
--fields-terminated-by="2C" \
--lines-terminated-by="0A"
```

[Load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) the `csv` file to a `BigQuery` table via `gcloud` cli and `bq` :

```bash
bq load \
  --source_format=CSV \
  mydataset.mytable \
  gs://mybucket/mydata.csv \
  ./myschema.json
```

`./myschema.json` is the `BigQuery` table schema.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
But, I will copy 300 table from MySQL to BigQuery, so I will using Cloud Dataflow, because if I use your step will be takes time. And I will copy 300 tables per day.
Any suggestion for my question?

Comment: What do you think about running my script in parallel ? You can do that with an orchestrator like Airflow, I can update my answer in this direction if you are interested. With Dataflow you will loose time with the the creation and destruction of short lived infra and VM.

Comment: So I will tell my project.
My project is copy 300 tables from MySQL to BigQuery with Dataflow (python script) then will schedulling per day with Airflow. So I still don't understand to etl from mysql to bigquery with dataflow with python script.